# MYSQL delete all emails if email_address is in second table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 email tables. 1 = main email table, 2 = bounce_table.

Field email = unique in both tables.

Tasks = delete from main_email_table where email is in bounce_table.

I have no idea how to make the right call for action for this task.

I hope to get an idea how to solve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check below query-

```
DELETE me.* FROM main_email AS me
JOIN bounce_email AS be ON me.email=be.email;
```

Comment: thanks it works also

Answer (score 0):

You need a `DELETE` with `JOIN`:

```
DELETE email_table
FROM email_table
INNER JOIN bounce_table ON bounce_table.email =  email_table.email
```